# Neovim suggestion selection menu

Tags: vim, neovim

Some menus in the neovim autocomplete suggestion can not be selected and I have no idea how to select them. I tried several keyboard shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>..., but none of them worked.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try combination: Ctrl Y.
Note: you should use Tab for moving to next item or Shift Tab to moving back to previous one in suggestion pane.